# Checkbox hide Hack

Tags: html, css

I try to hide/show the div "gametype" but if the input checkbox is in a list item the following code does not run and I don't understand why

and is it possible to disable the "pc" and "xbox" input with the "no-game" input without using js?

```css
input[type = checkbox]# no - game: checked~#gametype {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h3>Worauf spielst du:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input id="PC" name="PC" type="checkbox">
        <label for="PC" class="side-label">PC</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="Xbox" name="Xbox" type="checkbox">
        <label for="Xbox" class="side-label">Xbox</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="no-game" name="no-game" type="checkbox" checked>
        <label for="no-game" class="side-label">nichts</label>
      </li>
      <div id="gametype" class="gametype">
        <h3>Was spielst du:</h3>
        <li>
          <input id="MMO" name="MMO" type="checkbox">
          <label for="MMO" class="side-label">MMO</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="RPG" name="RPG" type="checkbox">
          <label for="RPG" class="side-label">RPG</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="Shooter" name="Shooter" type="checkbox">
          <label for="Shooter" class="side-label">Shooter</label>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. It should be:

```css
input#no-game:checked ~ #gametype {
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because the [~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) selector only match its siblings
to do it in a pure css way I would recommend to make the gametype element a sibling of the input

```css
input[type=checkbox]#no-game:checked ~ #gametype {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h3>Worauf spielst du:</h3> 
    
           
            <input id="PC" name="PC" type="checkbox">
            <label for="PC" class="side-label">PC</label>
       
            <input id="Xbox" name="Xbox" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Xbox" class="side-label">Xbox</label>
            
            
             <input id="no-game" name="no-game" type="checkbox" checked>
            <label for="no-game" class="side-label">nichts</label>
            
     
            
    
        <div id="gametype" class="gametype">
            <h3>Was spielst du:</h3> 
                <li> 
                    <input id="MMO" name="MMO" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="MMO" class="side-label">MMO</label>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <input id="RPG" name="RPG" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="RPG" class="side-label">RPG</label>
                </li>
                <li>  
                    <input id="Shooter" name="Shooter" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="Shooter" class="side-label">Shooter</label>
                </li>
        </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i know if i remvoe the list style it run fine, but it there a way to use the list style

Comment: It would be using js , but you can also make the input fields act as a list style.. with pure css

Comment: ok thank you :) some user block js so its a problem to use it^^

Answer (score 0):

Actually you missed a double quotes for checkbox text

```
input[type="checkbox"]#no-game:checked ~ #gametype  {
    display: none;
}
```